# $\lim\sup x_n = \infty$ and $\lim\inf x_n = - \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

I have the following question: is it true, whatever definition of a limit superior and a limit inferior of a sequence (say, in $\mathbb{R}$) we take, we would have

$\lim\sup x_n = \infty$ if $(x_n)$ is not bounded above,

$\lim\inf x_n = -\infty$ if $(x_n)$ is not bounded below?

I think this is true, but want to check if I'm correct. My reasoning:

> Suppose that $(x_n)$ is not bounded above (resp., below). Then $\sup_{k \geq n} x_k = \infty$ (resp., $\inf_{k \geq n} x_k = - \infty$) for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, because, were we to assume that, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\sup_{k \geq n} x_k < \infty$ (resp., $\sup_{k \geq n} x_k > - \infty$), we would have $\infty = \sup\{ x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \} = \max\{x_0, ..., x_{n-1}, \sup_{k \geq n} x_n \} \in \mathbb{R}$ (resp., $-\infty = \inf\{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} = \min\{x_0,...,x_{n-1},\inf_{k\geq n} x_n\} \in \mathbb{R}$), which is an obvious contradiction.

Now it should be clear that a limit of a constant sequence should be the constant in question, no matter what the definition of convergence we take in the extended number line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: If the sequence is in the extended reals then you can take any bounded sequence and replace any point with infinity. Then it is not bounded but the limsup exists. For it to not exist the sequence must be unbounded frequently (in the sense that for each index it is unbounded somewhere after it).

Comment: Your statement is true.